# How to make password change form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using has_secure_password method, how to make change password form and controller action?
I think it must look like:

```
<%= form_for @parent, :url => update_password_path(@parent) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :old_password %><br />
<%= f.text_field :old_password %><br />
<%= f.label :new_password %><br />
<%= f.text_field :password %><br />
<%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure how to do this the 'correct' by the standards way, but yeah, you would want a form like that. The controller action would check if the old password is valid by doing

```
user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
if user and user.authenticate(params[:old_password])
    if params[:password] == params[:password_confirmation]
        user.password_confirmation = BCrypt::Password.create(params[:password])
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # reset_password_success.html.erb
        end
    else
        redirect_to reset_password_url, notice: "Incorrect Password."
    end
else
    redirect_to reset_password_url, notice: "Incorrect Password."
end
```

Make sure you filter the passwords, just like they're filtered when a new user registers.

I don't know if your form will work or not. I find that if I'm stuck on how to create a form the right way, or in a hurry, I just hack it together using regular old HTML or use it as a crutch. Decide this based on your time constraints and past experience.

If the form is working correctly, but there is an error in handling the request, make sure that you really do access the params using params[:old_password] and such. It might be nested inside of another params object like params[:user][:old_password]. You can find out how the parameters are being sent by looking at your rails console, or by looking at the logs. If this is hosted on Heroku, you'll need to ask Heroku for it's logs => https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging
And you can also figure it out by listening to network traffic (dev tools on major browsers or using Fiddler => http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

This code is assuming that you're going off of the Agile Web Development with Rails (4th ed.) book. If not, then some adjustments will have to be made.